# My proposal has all the requisite users, what are we waiting for?

Tags: discussion, area-51

[My proposal, App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top) has 62 followers. According to the sidebar, it needs 5 on topic and 5 off topic to move on to the next stage. There are 33 sample questions, including more than enough of both kinds. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe it requires at least 20 votes to count a question as one of the ten required. Look at the proposals in the commit phase. Do you see any questions with <20?

Comment: Where is this information about vote thresholds stated stated?

Comment: @Moshe The [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah the rule for qualifying on-topic/off-topic questions is

> Each question needs 20 on-topic/off-topic votes, and 4 times as many on-topic/off-topic as off-topic/on-topic votes`.

You can find it by hovering over the question counts under the proposal status in the sidebar.  It's also in the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Looking at some like biblical hermaneutics reveals that it will accept numbers less than 20.

Comment: @John: That's because Biblical Hermeneutics finished it's definition phase more than a year ago.  The rules were a bit more lax then.

Comment: That makes sense. (Is there a way I can tell someone that I got their response without a little noise comment like this?)

Comment: @John You trying to get me to make more noi--DAMMIT.  Don't worry about it, we've got the bytes :)

Comment: Good to know.  :)

Answer (score 3):

What are you missing?  Voters.

In order for a question to count as one of the 10 you need, a question has to have at least X* votes of a specific type.

*I believe this number to be *around* 20.  Looking at a few other proposals in the commit phase, their examples *mostly* have >20 votes(I found a few with 18&19).  No examples in your proposal have >15.

Comment: How can I spur people to vote?

Comment: Aside from referring people, I don't know that you can. I believe the intent here is to have a general consensus among the interested as to what constitutes on or off topic.